# Extracting lines from nested json file using Ubuntu

Tags: json, ubuntu

I have nested json file (each field can have one or more sons) with many lines. Something like this:

```
{
    "id": "0001",
    "type": "donut",
    "name": "Cake",
    "ppu": 0.55,
    "batters":
        {
            "batter":
                [
                    { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
                    { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" },
                    { "id": "1003", "type": "Blueberry" },
                    { "id": "1004", "type": "Devil's Food" }
                ]
        },
    "topping":
        [
            { "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
            { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
            { "id": "5005", "type": "Sugar" },
            { "id": "5007", "type": "Powdered Sugar" },
            { "id": "5006", "type": "Chocolate with Sprinkles" },
            { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },
            { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
        ]
}
```

Using Ubuntu (or Unix) I would like to find the first 10 lines that their `"batters"` field is not empty (i.e. in the line one or more of its sons contain value (not null or "").

Comment: Can you use packages? `jq` is a great tool for doing this. Otherwise you can pipe json into a small python script

Comment: Both approaches are acceptable.

Comment: as suggested you should put forth effort to solve this using command line tool jq then show your jq command if need be